# PHP - Avoid writting nested if statement

Tags: php, variables, coding-style, isset, php-5.6

I have this variable:

```
$otcId;
```

which value can be retrieved from 3 different places(keep in mind this value will always be the same in all places):

```
$otcId = $this->dat['id_rfcOV'];
$otcId = $this->request['id_rfcOV'];
$otcId = $this->response['id_rfcOV'];
```

my approach was the following:

```
$otcId = $this->dat['id_rfcOV'];

if(isset($this->dat['id_rfcOV'])){
   $otcId = $this->dat['id_rfcOV'];
} elseif(isset($this->request['id_rfcOV'])) {
   $otcId = $this->request['id_rfcOV'];
} elseif(isset($this->response['id_rfcOV'])) {
   $otcId = $this->response['id_rfcOV'];
}
```

what would be a shorter better and more readable way to write this code?

Comment: This could be interesting for you: https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators

Comment: you could always add a getter which loops etc, example using array_reduce https://3v4l.org/0rfci

Comment: or a foreach https://3v4l.org/43Ibd

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would wrap this in a function, and use the [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) to simplify retrieval and the return of a default value.

```php
<?php

class MyController
{
    private array $dat = [];
    private array $request = ['id_rfcOV' => 'foo'];
    private array $response = ['id_rfcOV' => 'bar'];

    /**
     * @param string $name Parameter name
     * @param null $default Default value to return if no matching parameters are found
     * @return mixed|string|null
     */
    function getParam(string $name, $default=null)
    {
        return $this->dat[$name] ?? $this->request[$name] ?? $this->response[$name] ?? $default;
    }
    
    function test(): void
    {
        // Using a member function, we can get our parameter value with a one-liner
        $otcId = $this->getParam('id_rfcOV');

        assert($otcId == 'bar', 'Value should be from the last array checked');

        printf("Value is %s \n", $otcId);

        $val = $this->getParam('non-existent', 'wombats');

        assert($val == 'wombats', 'Value should be the default');

        printf("Value is %s \n", $val);
    }
}

$myController = new MyController();
$myController->test();
```

Comment: Although it’s not shorter like asked it’s much better and more robust- I like it! Maybe passing the dat/request/response parameter-name when calling -> test() would be even better.

Comment: Yeah, IRL you would clearly do something like that.

Comment: The code actually extracting the value is shorter- just one line. Wrapping it in a function makes it easier to use (and require less overall code) if you are pulling more than one value.